# Understanding Grep Pattern - Example

Tags: linux, design-patterns, grep

I am looking at an existing script, and am trying to understand what a certain line does. I  have the following command:

```
grep -v "[0-9]\{8\}030[0-9]\{4\}"
```

And can not understand in 'real' terms what I am looking for. I know since it is a -v, it is looking for every line that does not have this pattern int it; but cant figure out what the pattern is.

From what I can decipher, I think it should be looking for (using N to represent any number 0 through 9)
n{8}300n{4}; but this makes no sense since the log file it is searching for does not contain anything close to this. The log file being searched does contain a time string, such as 201401100528086; so Im sure the grep is excluding a certain time.. yet I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{n}` is a repeat count, which matches exactly `n` copies of the atom to its left. So we can break down that expression into these parts:

```
[0-9] {8}      - match 8 digits
030            - match "030" exactly
[0-9] {4}      - match 4 digits
```

So this pattern matches anything that contains `"########030####"` where each `#` is a digit 0 through 9.

If the strings it's checking are of the form `YYYYmmddHHMMSS` which seems to be the case, this pattern appears to be designed to match any time string that occurred between 3 AM and 3:10 AM.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to say : don't show me log entries where the hour was '3' and minute starts with '0' ( 0300 - 0309 )